# Compare the source of an image with png file

Tags: javascript

I need to compare the source of an image with a png file.

This line works (but I don't like it, security issues?):

```
if(event.target.src === 'file:///C:/Users/JLuc01/Desktop/.../rDot.png'){xDot = true;}
```

but, this one doesn't work:

```
if(event.target.src == 'rDot.png'){xDot = true;}
```

Do you have any ideas of resolving this issue (other property instead of src OR other strategy)? The images are created dynamically.

Here is the whole code context:

```
// SPOT - Mouseover event for each image
var xDot = false;
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('mouseover', function(event){
    clearInterval(t);
    if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'img'){
       if(event.target.src == 'rDot.png'){xDot = true;}
       event.target.src = 'bDot.png';
       console.log(xDot);
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help,

JLuc01

Comment: "this one doesn't work" doesn't tell anyone what the issue you are having is.  plus, the two aren't even similar to each other; aside from one using a path and the other not, one is using `===` and the other is using `==`.

Comment: Ooops, -4 . My question was apparently badly formulated. 'Doesn't work' means that xDot is never true in this case. But it is working with the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume when you make the comparison, you are getting the absolute path of the image (file://C:/User/.../rDot.png). To compare with the file name and its type then you can use the split function.

```
var src = event.target.src;
var split = src.split('/');
var file = split[split.length - 1];
```

You can then add your check using `if (file === 'rDot.png')`.

Comment: Great. You understood my question very well. Your answer is spot on. Sorry, I can't put +1, because I am new there and my reputation is below 15 (and with -4, it is probably not going up). Anyway, my main goal is to find an answer, then thanks again.

Comment: No worries, glad I was able to help! :)